# How can I use useState? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs

How can I use `useState`? What am I doing wrong?

Im using useState in `SwitchNameHandler`.
Thanks for help!

```js
import './App.css';
import Some from './Some/Some';
import {useState} from "react/cjs/react.production.min";

const App = () => {

    const state = {
        persons: [
            {name: 'Connor', text: 'This is first h2.'},
            {name: 'Megan', text: 'This is second h2.'},
            {name: 'Jacob', text: 'This is third h2.'}
        ]
    };
    const SwitchNameHandler = () => {
        const [persons, setInfo] = useState(0)
        console.log('Button clicked')
        setInfo({
            persons: [
                {name: 'Andrew', text: 'This is first h2 after using button.'},
                {name: 'Andy', text: 'This is second h2 after using button.'},
                {name: 'John', text: 'This is third h2 after using button.'}
            ]
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hi, React!</h1>
            <button onClick={SwitchNameHandler}>Button</button>
            <Some name={state.persons[0].name} text={state.persons[0].text} > Children?</Some>
            <Some name={state.persons[1].name} text={state.persons[1].text} />
            <Some name={state.persons[2].name} text={state.persons[2].text} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I get this error:
`Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the `useState` hook from a minified file, try to import it like this

`import React, { useState } from 'react';`

and make sure to check out the documentation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Now i get `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.`

What I do wrong in my code?

Comment: I suggest you to checkout that link: https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call, "You might have more than one copy of React in the same app" is a very strange error to get... Did you use CRA to generate the project?

Answer (score 0):

In functional components managing state is different from class based components.No need to include persons in setInfo.
And you should populate or set data in a function call.

```
   const [persons, setInfo] = useState([])
   console.log('Button clicked')

   const clicked = () => {
         setInfo(
                [
                    {name: 'Andrew', text: 'This is first h2 after using button.'},
                    {name: 'Andy', text: 'This is second h2 after using button.'},
                    {name: 'John', text: 'This is third h2 after using button.'}
                ]
            )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move state outside of the SwitchNameHandler function and access the state directly

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
const state = [
  { name: "Connor", text: "This is first h2." },
  { name: "Megan", text: "This is second h2." },
  { name: "Jacob", text: "This is third h2." }
];
export default function App() {
  const [persons, setInfo] = useState(state);

  const SwitchNameHandler = () => {
    setInfo([
      { name: "Andrew", text: "This is first h2 after using button." },
      { name: "Andy", text: "This is second h2 after using button." },
      { name: "John", text: "This is third h2 after using button." }
    ]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi, React!</h1>
      <button onClick={SwitchNameHandler}>Button</button>
      {persons.map((person) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{person.name}</h1>
          <p>{person.text}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ramanujan-dcdem?file=/src/App.js